# Installshield installation ask the user to have iisadmin on a machine with iis7 installed

Tags: iis, iis-7, installation, windows-installer, installshield

I am creating an installation that is adding a web site to IIS. But when I am trying to run the installation on a machine with IIS 7 installed and IIS 6 compatibility mode not installed, it fails the installation with:

> Error 1920.Service IISADMIN (IISADMIN) failed to start. Verify that
>   you have sufficient privileges to start system services

If I install the compatibility feature it fixes the problem and the installation succeeds.
I want to know if there is a way to not install this feature on IIS 7.
Or if it must be installed - how can I install it automatically?

btw, I have installShield 2011 Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually what I did is to run as custom actions this lines

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-Metabase
```

and use as condition Not Installed and IIS_VERSION > "#6"

Thanks for Cosmin Privu help
Ben

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the compatibility fix as a custom prerequisite to your package:
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/SetupPrereqEditor.htm

For example you can create a custom EXE which uses [pkmgr.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749465%28WS.10%29.aspx) to install the **IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility** feature (it's like installing it from Control Panel).

It can be configured to install only when it's not found and only if IIS 7 is installed. This way you can make sure that the service can always be started for IIS 7.

Comment: I am sorry buy I still don't understand why I need this file to be installed. and if I decide it to be install how I force it to get installed with my installation. Thanks, Ben

Comment: The compatibility problem is most likely related to your web application. Can you install it manually on a IIS 7 machine which doesn't have the fix? Regarding the fix installer, you can add it as a prerequisite. Did you read the article I mentioned? A prerequisite is another installer which gets installed with your package.

Comment: First of all thanks. and yes I read the article you mentioned. and I understand the issue of prerequisite. but how can I say to him to install the compatibility feature I didn't understand that good.

Comment: Prerequisites are launched automatically if they need to be installed. You don't have to instruct the user about it.

Comment: yes this I understand but what is the prerequisite of the windows compatibility feature. thanks for your patience, Ben.

Comment: You can create a custom EXE which installs it and add that EXE as a prerequisite. I edited my answer.